# Generating primal solution from dual solution of a LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How to get the primal solution from a dual solution in general?

For example, let the primal problem is

$$
\text {maximize } 2r_1+2r_2-2c_1-2c_2
$$
where
$$
r_1-c_1\leq1\\
r_1-c_2\leq1\\
r_2-c_1\leq1\\
r_2-c_2\leq1\\
-r_1+c_1\leq1\\
-r_1+c_2\leq1\\
-r_2+c_1\leq1\\
-r_2+c_2\leq1
$$

Then the dual can be formulated as

$$\text{minimize }
e_{11}+e_{12}+e_{21}+e_{22}+f_{11}+f_{12}+f_{21}+f_{22}
$$

where
$$
e_{11}+e_{12}-f_{11}-f_{12} \geq 2\\
e_{21}+e_{22}-f_{21}-f_{22} \geq 2\\
-e_{11}-e_{21}+f_{11}+f_{21} \geq -2\\
-e_{12}-e_{22}+f_{12}+f_{22} \geq -2
$$

Here $e_{ij}$ corresponds to the primal equation $r_i - c_j \leq 1$ and $f_{ij}$ corresponds to the primal equation $-r_i + c_j \leq 1$

An optimal solution of the dual is $e_{11}=e_{22}=2$ and $e_{12}=e_{21}=f_{11}=f_{12}=f_{21}=f_{22}=0$

Now using Complementary Slackness Theorem, we have $r_1-c_1=r_2-c_2=1$

But only using these two equations we can't get a solution for $(r_1,r_2, c_1, c_2)$

Any other method?

Comment: What is the Definition set of the variables at the primal problem ? If it is $\mathbb R$ for all variables, then the constraints (dual problem) have to have an equality-sign(**=**).

Comment: Yes, it is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Then there are only equality signs at the dual problem. And the definition set for all variables of the dual problem is $\geq 0$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Duality

Comment: What is your intention by posting this link ?

Comment: "there are only equality signs at the dual problem" - not necessarily if the dual is symmetric.

Comment: But it seems to be asymmetric, because $x \in \mathbb R$ and NOT $x \geq 0$.